# Blinking images in the buttons in table cells while scrolling table (Eclipse RAP Platform)

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I added checkbox button in the JFace table cell using TableEditor class.

```
for (TableItem tableItem : tableViewer.getTable().getItems()) {
        TestData testData = (TestData) tableItem.getData();

        Button button = new Button(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.CHECK);
        button.setSelection(testData .checked);
        button.setData(testData);

        TableEditor tableEditor = new TableEditor(tableViewer.getTable());
        tableEditor.grabHorizontal = true;
        tableEditor.minimumWidth = button.getSize().x;
        tableEditor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        tableEditor.setEditor(button, tableItem, COLUMN_INDEX_WITH_CHECKBOX);
    }
```

When I scrolling checkbox icons displaying with delay.
How can I fix it?